# How can I design a GUI run button for my Python script? The button which only responsible for click to run the script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, coding-style, python-imaging-library

I have prepared a ***python*** automation script, I want to design a ***GUI button*** which should have the only function to run the script instead of run a command like below in **terminal**.

```
python3 media/path/xyz.py
```

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In particular, "How do I implement this feature" is discussed as being off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `os.startfile()` or `subprocess.call()`

> Here is a small example for your reference

```py
from tkinter import *
import os
#import subprocess
root=Tk()
def run_p():
    os.startfile('media//path//xyz.py')
    #Or
    #subprocess.call('C:\\myprogram.py')
btn=Button(root,text='Click',command=run_p).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by a *GUI* button to launch your script.

Usually, a GUI requires to launch a python script to launch your GUI. If you want to launch a script by *clicking on it*, you can double click on your ".py" file if you have a system interpreter with all the desired packages and your code should run just fine.